# How to remove View Details from a field in a Form?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

How to remove View Details from a field in Dynamics AX 2012 Form?

When you right click on a field with a relation with DataSource's Table, you'll find View Details in context menu, How to remove this option.

[image: View Details]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a workaround. You can override jumpRef() method of DataSoruce Field and comment super, View Details will appear but it'll not go to Main Form.

```
public void jumpRef()
{
    //super();
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to avoid the collateral problems caused if you remove the relations that Jan stays on another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "View details" appears if there is a foreign key relation (n->1) with the field as the last component.

You could remove the relation, but it may other bad effects, you will have to consider.

Comment: I know removing Relation will make erorr that's why I used the workaround I mentioned.